# buf = string.getbytes() inconsistent results

Tags: java, sockets, udp, client-server

When I call the `getBytes()` method on a string I get inconsistent results, first time the statement is executed it is only returning the first 3 characters of the string, If I call upon that statement again it returns the full String, but It also randomly returns only the first 3 characters every so often. A snippet of the code from my server class is as follows:

```
String reply = ("Current list of users includes: " + users);
buf = reply.getBytes();
packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, port);
socket.send(packet);
```

On the client receiving end I then have the following;

```
socket.receive(packet);
String response = new String(packet.getData());
System.out.println("ChatClient: Response from Server: " + response);
```

The first time that this is called all that is printed is "Cur", Then the second time it is called the full string is printed along with the values stored in 'users'.

Is there anyway to ensure that this operates correctly the first time round and in a consistent manner?

Comment: how do you initialize the packet at the client?

Comment: I feel there could be many possibilities - wrong charset, incorrect input

Comment: I have to use UDP, as its the in the criteria for the assignment for uni.

Comment: I have      static byte[] buf = new byte[512];
            static InetAddress address = null;
            static int port = 0;
            static DatagramPacket packet = null;                    as global declarations   then                                                   public static void newUser(String host) throws SocketException, UnknownHostException, IOException 
    {
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();                         then the socket is passed to startChat method where i print the response

Comment: @JoeMurphy at the client? `DatagramSocket.receive(null)` would fail with a `NullpointerException`.

Comment: Try printing value of packet.getLength() on client side to show if packets are somehow getting truncated.